# Creating related entities in a restful way

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, rest

An `Account` can have a `Contact` associated with it.

We have a `POST` endpoint that will create an Account.

```
    [Route("Account", Name = "CreateAccount", Order = 1)]
    [HttpPost]
    public Account CreateAccount([FromBody] Account account)
    {
        var newAccount = _accountService.CreateAccountEntity(account);
        return newAccount;
    }
```

**Would it be RESTful to allow the consumer to associate an *existing* `Contact` to the newly-created `Account`?**

Comment: Do you mean to add `Contact` to `Account` in the same `CreateAccount` method?

Comment: yes i do. good question

Comment: Then in my subjective opinion - no, it is not technically RESTful; however, as we live in a less than perfect world, I think it is OK as long as you modify your URI and method signature to make it clear you don't just create an account, but instead you perform such logic as well.